# Can a Cycles/Blender Internal materials be shared on their own?

Tags: python, materials

I would like to know how I can export a material to let a friend use, without sending them a huge .blend file just to append the material from.

Comment: Couldn't you just append the material into a new .blend and send them that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While its possible to invent some file-format to store Blender materials, this is currently not a common way to share materials.

Typically for this would be done by appending materials into a new Blend file, saving it, and sending this to a 3rd party.

In rare cases a material may depend on objects (using empties for mapping), in those cases you could create a group of objects in your Blend file and append that instead of the materials (the materials will load in too).

Answer (score 2):

There is one option for cycles materials - [Online Material Library](http://peter.cassetta.info/material-library/). It is in the [contrib addons](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BAC/) that is normally included with non-release builds.

Primarily this addon provides access to a collection of materials but also has tools to import/export cycles node based materials to an xml-based text file that can easily be shared. While there was mention of adding support for BI materials there hasn't been any support added for them.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is put the material on a cube in the original file. Maybe pack the file if it includes images. Then copy-paste the cube to an empty blend file and share this. I think this would be about the minimal space requirement.